# Select Embedded Internet Explorer Version

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, vmware

I am developing a web based plug-in application that needs to be supported by the Embedded Browser given on the [vSphere Client from VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/overview.html)

I found out that it does not matter which version of Internet Explorer I have installed on my Windows, the embedded browser used by vSphere is always the Internet Explorer version 7. (I found that out using a JavaScript + JQuery).
I already tried to force the version of the used Internet Explorer with the user-agent (and similars) but with no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

My web application is only compatible with **Internet Explorer 8 or later**, so my question is how can I force the Embedded Internet Explorer to use the 8 or later version?

Comment: if IE7 is all that's installed on the VM then that's what it'll run. You won't be able to force it to run IE8 without upgrading the version installed on the VM.